# Why did Valancin Taulaj refer to himself as a jailed Communist in this poem?

Tags: poetry, belarusian-language, like-water-like-fire, valancin-taulaj

In his poem *Last Words*, Valancin Taulaj wrote:

> I am a Communist! there are many like me
> In this our land that from the dawn of time has growned,
> Never shall magnates crush us, though they strike us,
> By jails and gallows we're not overthrown!

He also refers to being condemned under laws written by the Tsar.

However, the author was born in 1914. The Tsar fell in 1918 (when he was only four), and the USSR took over Belarus in 1920 (when he was only six).

That being said, why does the author seem to be referring to himself? Was he actually a Communist, and was he actually jailed for it?

Comment: It's perfectly possible that he's writing about another man's last words, in the past.